# How to parse kubernetes pattern log with Filebeat

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat

I've got Kubernetes cluster with ECK Operator deployed. I also deploy Filebeat to my cluster. Here's file:

```
apiVersion: beat.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Beat
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: logging-dev
spec:
  type: filebeat
  version: 8.2.0
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elastic-logging-dev
  kibanaRef:
    name: kibana
  config:
    filebeat:
      autodiscover:
        providers:
          - type: kubernetes
            node: ${NODE_NAME}
            hints:
              enabled: true
              default_config:
                type: container
                paths:
                  - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log
    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata: { }
      - add_host_metadata: { }
  daemonSet:
    podTemplate:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          co.elastic.logs/enabled: "false"
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: filebeat
        automountServiceAccountToken: true
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
        hostNetwork: true # Allows to provide richer host metadata
        tolerations:
          - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
            effect: NoSchedule
          - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
            effect: NoSchedule
        containers:
          - name: filebeat
            securityContext:
              runAsUser: 0
            volumeMounts:
              - name: varlogcontainers
                mountPath: /var/log/containers
              - name: varlogpods
                mountPath: /var/log/pods
              - name: varlibdockercontainers
                mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
            env:
              - name: NODE_NAME
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: 500Mi
                cpu: 100m
              limits:
                memory: 500Mi
                cpu: 200m
        volumes:
          - name: varlogcontainers
            hostPath:
              path: /var/log/containers
          - name: varlogpods
            hostPath:
              path: /var/log/pods
          - name: varlibdockercontainers
            hostPath:
              path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

It's working very well, but I want to also parse Kubernetes logs, eg.:

```
E0819 18:57:51.309161       1 watcher.go:327] failed to prepare current and previous objects: conversion webhook for minio.min.io/v2, Kind=Tenant failed: Post "https://operator.minio-operator.svc:4222/webhook/v1/crd-conversion?timeout=30s": dial tcp 10.233.8.119:4222: connect: connection refused
```

How can I do that?

In Fluentd it's quite simple:

```
<filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.kube-apiserver-*_kube-system_*.log>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  format /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)$/
  time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
  types pid:integer
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field false
</filter>
```

But I cannot find any example, tutorial or whatever how to do this with Filebeat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing k8s docker container json log correctly with Filebeat 7.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860153/parsing-k8s-docker-container-json-log-correctly-with-filebeat-7-9-3)

Comment: @Adiii unfortunately not, the question you pasted was about how to parse JSON, I know how to parse JSON in Filebeat. I need to parse example I provide.

Comment: The parsing part can be done by Logstash using Grok expressions. So the path would be filebeat --> logstash --> elastic. They can all run fine on kubernetes. An example here: https://raphaeldelio.medium.com/deploy-logstash-and-filebeat-on-kubernetes-with-eck-ssl-and-filebeat-d9f616737390